# Bouncy castle light weight api encryption for j2me - Given final block not properly padded

Tags: encryption, java-me, cryptography, padding, bouncycastle

i have used **sha256** for secret key generation and took first **16 digit** for **AES 128** encryption. i am getting correct encrypted and decrypted data when it is 16 or below 16 string. if it is above 16 char string i am getting 16 char with some unwanted characters. (Eg: abcdefghijklmnop5@�D�!�&M�\~C��) can anybody help me to sort this issue. please see below for code.

i have encrypted using j2me code and tried to decrypt using the given online aes crypto site (http://aesencryption.net/). i guess it is having some padding issue but i am not able to figure it out.

```
public static String getSHA256(String key) {
    SHA256Digest digester = new SHA256Digest();
    byte[] retValue = new byte[digester.getDigestSize()];
    digester.update(key.getBytes(), 0, key.length());
    digester.doFinal(retValue,0);

    byteToStr = new String(Hex.encode(retValue));
    System.out.println("byteToStr === " + byteToStr);
    byteToStr = byteToStr.substring(0, 16);
    System.out.println("byteToStr after subString === " + byteToStr);
    return byteToStr;

}

public static byte[] cipherData(BufferedBlockCipher cipher, byte[] data)
        throws Exception {
    int minSize = cipher.getOutputSize(data.length);
    System.out.println("min Size = "+minSize);
    byte[] outBuf = new byte[minSize];
    int length1 = cipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, outBuf, 0);
    int length2 = cipher.doFinal(outBuf, length1);
    System.out.println("length1 = "+length1 +"/ length2 = "+length2);
    int actualLength = length1 + length2;
    System.out.println("actualLength = "+actualLength);
    byte[] result = new byte[actualLength];
    System.arraycopy(outBuf, 0, result, 0, result.length);
    return result;

}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipher, byte[] key/* , byte[] iv */)
        throws Exception {
    /*
     * PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher( new
     * CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine())); CipherParameters ivAndKey = new
     * ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv); aes.init(false,
     * ivAndKey); return cipherData(aes, cipher);
     */
    BufferedBlockCipher decryptCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
            new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));

    KeyParameter keyDecrypt = new KeyParameter(key);

    decryptCipher.init(false, keyDecrypt);
    return cipherData(decryptCipher, cipher);

}

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plain, byte[] key/* , byte[] iv */)
        throws Exception {
    /*
     * PaddedBufferedBlockCipher aes = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher( new
     * CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine())); CipherParameters ivAndKey = new
     * ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
     */

    BufferedBlockCipher encryptCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
            new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()));

    KeyParameter keyEncrypt = new KeyParameter(key);
    encryptCipher.init(true, keyEncrypt);
    return cipherData(encryptCipher, plain);

}

public static String encryptMe(String plain) {
    byte[] plainStr = plain.getBytes();
    byte[] keyStr = getSHA256(key).getBytes();
    // byte[] ivStr = iv.getBytes();//
    System.out.println("key str = "+Strings.fromByteArray(keyStr));

    try {
        byte[] encBytes = encrypt(plainStr, keyStr/*
                                                 * , ivStr
                                                 */);
        strEncResult= Base64.toBase64String(encBytes);
        //byte[] encbase = Base64.encode(encBytes);
        //strEncResult = new String(encbase,"ISO-8859-1");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return strEncResult;
}

public static String decryptMe(String cipherText) {

    try {
        byte[] dcrByte = Base64.decode(cipherText);
        byte[] dec = decrypt(dcrByte, getSHA256(key).getBytes()/*
                                                                 * ,iv.getBytes
                                                                 * ()
                                                                 */);
        strDcrResult = Strings.fromByteArray(dec);
        //strDcrResult = new String(dec,"ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return strDcrResult;

}
```

Comment: Am i doing anything wrong in base64 encoding / decoding. how to find if any thing went wrong over there?

Comment: I tried your code with a normal java jdk and it works just fine. Tried it with data with a length of 1 and way more than 16. Always with `key = "pwd"`. Could it be something with java me or are you doing something else different? I just called `String encryptMe = encryptMe(tmp);
  String decryptMe = decryptMe(encryptMe);` and all imports from BC (jdk15on-1.51)

Comment: Thanks jan for the reply, what you are saying is you got an encrypted string and you decrypted it also. here is the scenario. take the encrypted string and use the onlie aes tool to decrypt it using the same key(16 digit).http://aesencryption.net/. then i am getting above given data .it is correct till 16 character after that i am getting some special chatacter